# Bound quiver algebras with relations of the form $x_ix_j=$sum of paths of length $\geqslant 3$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

While working with homotopes and isotopes of finite dimensional algebras I often encounter algebras isomorphic to a path algebra of a bound quiver, i.e. $k[\Gamma]/I$, where the relations $I$ have the form $x_ix_j=P_{i,j}$, where $x_i,x_j$ are arrows in the quiver and $P_{i,j}$ is a linear combination of paths of length $\geqslant 3$.

Is there a name for such algebras? Is anything known about them? I am particularly interested in whether there are finitely many isomorphism classes of such algebras of given dimension (or with a fixed quiver $\Gamma$).

The easiest example of an infinite family of pair-wise non-isomorphic algebras is the family $A_\lambda=k\langle x,y\rangle/(x^2,y^2,xy-\lambda yx),$ where $k\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes a free algebra on two generators. These 4-dimensional algebras are pairwise non-isomorphic, except for the pairs $A_\lambda$ and $A_{1/\lambda}.$  There are 5 such one-parameter families in dimension 5, but none of them are of the above sort.